# How do I keep the page I'm on within the URL when running a search on a taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, search

I'm trying out a couple of plugins to aid in searching of taxonomy terms. One is called "Query Multiple Taxonomies" and the other is called "Drop-down-custom-taxonomy".

What I'm wanting to keep the page I'm searching from when I begin the search. For example if the page I'm on is dogs (www.site.com/dogs) and I run a search on this page for a taxonomy called "breed", and find all dogs that are a "beagle", the url is changed to this:

www.site.com/?breed=beagle

How can I get the url to stay with /dogs in it?

www.site.com/dogs/?breed=beagle

Based on my limited knowledge, I'd say this is a job for url rewriting? I did try adding some code for a base url for Query Multiple Taxonomies but this did not work with my permalink structure of /%year%/%postname%/

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `action` attribute of your search form in your theme, for example;

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url( $GLOBALS['wp']->request ); ?>" method="get">
```

This will dynamically output the URL of the current request, so that when a user searches, the query string is simply *appended* to it, rather than pointing back at the root.

Comment: Thanks, nice tip. This fixes the default WP search box but it doesn't have any effect on the taxonomy dropdowns I am using. They still start searching from the homepage. 

I found that Query Multiple Taxonomies has a "base URL" filter that can be set but it doesn't work with my /%year%/%postname%/ permalinks. https://github.com/scribu/wp-query-multiple-taxonomies/wiki/Changing-URLs

Comment: The other plugin uses the following. Perhaps I can modify the window.location.href?

`<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("select#{$id}").change(function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).val();
  });
 });
</script>`